# Why does focusing my text input in a directive constructor not work when it's triggered from an ngIf?

Tags: angular, input, focus

Please have a look at this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnjw1s

It demonstrates how a text input can be put into focus by selecting it with a directive and calling focus() on the nativeElement in the constructor.

Now please have a look at this variant:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsrhpr

This is the same thing except it includes a toggle button which toggles the visibility of the text input using ngIf. It seems that in this case, calling focus() on the nativeElement doesn’t work. You know it’s being called from the console logs. For some reason, in this case, it doesn’t want to focus.

Can anyone see why?

EDIT: I appears that the link at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsrhpr doesn't show you the version I intended. I'm unable to save on stackblitz.

Here is the code you're supposed to see. Please copy and paste:

app.component.html:

```
<input *ngIf="b" focus>
<button (click)="b = !b">Toggle</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  b = false;
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { FocusDirective } from './focus.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, FocusDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

focus.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective {

  constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
    console.log('before focusing');
    elm.nativeElement.focus();
    console.log('after focusing');
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsrhpr doesnt have the code you're talking about, it is basiic boilerplate code from SB

Comment: I made an edit with the code you're suppose to see.

Comment: *ngIf removes the element from the DOM, and since it is non-existent, you'll get undefined when you `elm.nativeElement.focus();` in the directive... this is normal behavior

Answer (score 1):

*ngIf removes the element from the DOM, and since it is non-existent, you'll get undefined when you elm.nativeElement.focus(); in the directive... this is normal behavior

you can use the CSS visibility property which hides the element, but the element does become part of the DOM.

**directive.ts**:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective {

  constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
    console.log('before focusing');
    elm.nativeElement.focus();
    console.log('after focusing');
  }
}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<input focus [ngStyle]="{'visibility':fieldVisible === true ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }"> <br/> 

so a page when loads, sets the focus to the input box
<br/>
<button type='button' (click)='toggleVisibility()'>toggle</button>
 <br/>
 Field visibility is: {{fieldVisible}}
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  fieldVisible: boolean = false;
  toggleVisibility() {
    (this.fieldVisible == true) ? this.fieldVisible = false : this.fieldVisible = true;
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y4lnsd)

Comment: Thanks Akber, I assumed that when the directive constructor was called, the element exists in the DOM. But I guess it exists in the DOM after the constructor? Is there a lifecycle hook and I can use after the element is added to the DOM?

Comment: Hi @gib65, your stackblitz `zsrhpr` is now forked into https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kddj61 ... as you can see that since `b` is false the directive wouldn't be loaded and no messages on the console. when you toggle to set `b` to true... the DOM hadn't loaded when the constructor is called, but by the time that **ngOnInit** is called, the DOM was loaded and you get the focus to your input element